# firebase callable function appends -default during deployment

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm not sure why, but when I try to deploy following callable function, in cli and firebase dashboard it's name is always appended with `-default`

src/helloWorld.ts

```
import {region} from "firebase-functions"

async function handler(input, context) {
  return "Hello World"
}

export default region('europe-west3').runWith({ memory: '2GB' }).https.onCall(handler);
```

index.ts

```
import admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp();

export const hellloWorld = require('./src/helloWorld');
```

I'd expect this callable function to be called just `helloWorld` when deployed, but instead it is `helloWorld-default`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by a feature of Firebase Functions called [function groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/organize-functions#group_functions) and that `require` works differently for modules.

With `src/helloWorld.ts` the way you have it, the statement `require('./src/helloWorld')` returns an object that looks like this:

```
{
  default: (input, context) => { /* ... */ }
}
```

In your `index.ts` file, you export this object as `helloWorld` (correcting for the typo). When you deploy the functions directory, it sees this exported object and decides to export each of it's properties prefixed with the export name (`exportedName-propertyNameOfExportedObject`) which gives `helloWorld-default`.

To get the behaviour you are expecting, explicitly export the default property:

```
export const helloWorld = require('./src/helloWorld').default;
```